# Stop/start a Windows service with a specific path?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, windows-services

I would like to create some scripts (Windows Batch or PowerShell, whichever will work) that can stop and start services that have their binPath in a specific folder. It will speed things up when debugging the software, since I often need to stop 4 services, modify configuration files, then start 4 services again. If I could have a script that could stop and start these services at the click of a button it would really speed up my workflow, and would also be useful for others using the software.

The software would be run from a location like: `C:\MyProgram`, and the 4 services would be in `C:\MyProgram\bin` for example.

I would like the script to stop `service1.exe`, `service2.exe`, etc. inside the bin directory when I run my script.

Is it possible to use `sc stop` in Windows Batch or `Stop-Service` in PowerShell to pass in a binPath parameter?

I have had a look at the documentation for these commands but cannot find a way to achieve this. Perhaps I need to do this as a sequence of several commands, but which ones I need I do not know.

Comment: Why do you think you need the path to the service? Both sc stop and Stop-Service work just fine stopping/starting a service by name.

Comment: That's true, but at this point I do not know what the service name is, only that the service is running from a specific location.

Comment: This strikes me as a strange condition. Why wouldn't you know the service name?

Comment: Because the service names are dynamic and not implied in any way by the current working directory of the script.

Comment: Could it be that you are mistaking the service name and service display name by chance?

`get-service wuauserv | format-list name,displayname`
returns this:
`Name        : wuauserv
DisplayName : Windows Update`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't trivial, but you could iterate through the registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services. The ImagePath key contains the executable name. Once you find that, use the service name to control the service.
Powershell would make this pretty easy using get-childitem and the path `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, I managed to work with the developers of the software to leave behind a trace of the service names separated by newline in a text file once the software is installed.

This way, I am easily able to start and stop the services using some simple PowerShell:

```
$services = Get-Content("services.txt").Split()
foreach ($service in $services) {
    Start-Service $service
}
```

This is much easier than trying to detect the services.